# SciPy ODR: How to specify bounds for my variables?

Tags: python, regression, scipy-optimize, non-linear-regression

I'm using `scipy.ODR` to fit a nonlinear function to my data. While the overall fit looks reasonable, I find that occasionally one of my fitted variables becomes unphysically large. Is there a way that I can specify that my fitted parameters can't exceed a defined range? I know that `scipy.optimize.bounds` can be used to specify such limits when using `scipy.optimize.minimize`, but I've not been able to find any similar option when using ODR.

Comment: Apparently I can't do this because `scipy.odr` uses ODRPACK77, which does not allow for parameter constraints. I will need to code my own solution outside of Python using ODRPACK95.